# What is the default sequential order of the file in postgres DB

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I wonder if Postgres use its primary key as the clustering index by default?

If no `CLUSTER` command is used, what will be the sequence order of the file? Will that be the same as the primary key?

Comment: Postgres does not have "clustered indexes"

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is quite clear:

> Clustering is a one-time operation: when the table is subsequently updated, the changes are not clustered. That is, no attempt is made to store new or updated rows according to their index order.

Clustering is a one-time operation.  It is not a property of the table.  Hence, there is no "clustering index by default" -- assuming that you mean that the table is maintained in that order.

Comment: so what is the order of the new or updated rows? by their arrival time?

Comment: @GeauxEric . . . There is no order.  SQL tables represent *unordered* multi-sets (sets that can have duplicate elements).